# Multiplying every cell within a range by a value

Tags: excel, vba

I would like that the value of every cell within a range is multiplied by a specific value (let's say 4/7). I have this code, but I'm getting a "Type mismatch error".

```
Range("B1:B4").Value = Range("B1:B4").Value * 4 / 7
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will do the whole at once:

```
Range("B1:B4").Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(B1:B4 * 4 / 7,)")
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Just to show.  I ran this:

```
Sub foo()
Dim t
t = Now()
[B:B] = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(row(B:B)*1,)")
[B:B] = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(B:B * 4 / 7,)")
Dim x

Debug.Print (Now() - t) * 24 * 60 * 60
End Sub
```

Which fills the entire column B with the row number of the cell, then does the math that is required.

It took 2 seconds to do the entire 1 million + rows.

[image]

Comment: Will this be too slow if I have a very large range?

Comment: Not that I have noticed.  It will be faster than looping. @N.Pavon

Comment: Every time I use an "Evaluate" function in VBA, it takes a while to actually evaluate the expression if the expression includes a large range. I'll check.

Comment: @N.Pavon Just did the full column.  It took less than 1 second.

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks.

Comment: How can I add a variable to the Evaluate part? For example, the last row of the Range.

Comment: `Range("B1:B" & lastrow).Value = ActiveSheet.Evaluate("INDEX(B1:B" & lastrow & " * 4 / 7,)")` @N.Pavon

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop:

```
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("B1:B4").Cells
    c.Value = c.Value * 4 / 7
Next c
```

Comment: Fixed -- I was just coding Python a little bit ago and forgot the VBA word "each"