# Multiply a range with a constant

Tags: vba, excel

I want to multiply everything within the range by a value. I tried this format, but the values became way off.

Code :

```
Dim yl1 As Range

Set yl1 = .Range(.Cells(17, 6), .Cells(n + 16, 6))*19.25
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36925222/multiplying-every-cell-within-a-range-by-a-value/36925326#36925326

Answer (score 2):

As per the link:

```
Dim yl1 as Range
Set yl1 = .Range(.Cells(17, 6), .Cells(n + 16, 6))
yl1.Value = .Evaluate("INDEX(" & yl1.Address(0,0) & " * 19.25,)")
```

It will do them all at once.

Comment: it works very well, but when I repeat the process the values seem to multiply it selft again for example it will do 3*19.25 for the first attempt then 3*19.25*19.25 for the second attempt and it keeps increasing.How do I clear the range one it is done using it.

Comment: I guess I am not understanding.  Do not loop this.  It does the whole range at one time.  If you want to loop then use @MattCremeens answer.  This would go after any loop.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably other ways, many of them probably better, but one is just a loop

```
For i = 17 to some last row
    Cells(i, 6) = Cells(i, 6) * 19.25
Next i
```

I find this way the most intuitive, though.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
Sub UsingPaste()
    Range("B1").Value = 0.7
    Range("B1").Copy
    n = 10
    Range(Cells(17, 6), Cells(n + 16, 6)).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlMultiply
End Sub
```

Where **B1** is some un-used cell and **n** is whatever it happens to be.